# How to connect MySQL and google sheet via JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I am using cafe24 which is the hosting site for mySQL. So, I want to fetch data from mysql to Google Spreadsheet. I know that it can be done via JDBC, so I tried it but the connection error occured Failed to establish a database connection. This is my code for connection.

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/show981111",
  "show981111", "dyd1@tmdwlsfl");
```

After then, I found that when using other database

> you must whitelist certain IP ranges in your database settings

from google scripts site. However, I don't know how to whitelist certain IP ranges. I found that I can allow the access to MySQL from other IP in the cafe24 site, but I can register only one IP address which is for my IP address.

Comment: oh! Also I am trying to use mysql workbench to whitelist, but I can't because when I trying to access to users and privileges, the alert says that the account i am currently using does not have sufficient privileges.

Comment: First you may want to remove any sensitive data from your post such as your MySQL login info. Second you need to contact your hosting provider (cafe24) and obtain IP address info for their hosting service (they may also be available directly via admin tools offered on their site) so that you can white-list them.

Comment: Instead of using localhost  try using the ip address:3306

Comment: I changed localhost to ip address, but it didn't work..